# .apk files not getting created on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to run an android project on eclipse juno and testing it on samsung tab 10.1.
The .apk file of the project is getting created on my comp but it is not getting loaded properly on the tab.
Could someone help me fix this?

Edit: Android version is 4.1.2 this is same as the tab. The error am getting from the tab is "Unfortunately AppName has stopped.". This same project is working fine on another machine. I have just imported the codebase in my eclipse.

The Log is as follows.

```
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.belgium.initial/com.belgium.initial.initial}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.belgium.initial.initial
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2021)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.belgium.initial.initial
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2012)
06-22 12:46:44.260: E/AndroidRuntime(25528):    ... 11 more
```

The Android Manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
  package="com.belgium.initial" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
<supports-screens      
    android:xlargeScreens="true"

    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Presbelg"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
   >
    <activity android:name=".initial" android:label="Presbelg"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you want to export apk? or if you mean you just want unsigned apk, apk is created each time you run the application in your projects bin folder.

Comment: I've changed my question. The .apk file is getting created properly but is not getting loaded properly on the tab

Comment: does it give some error in logcat?

Comment: that's a crash pls post your logcat details of the crash and the code. `Unfortunately AppName has stopped`. This means your app crashed.

Comment: Will do that immediately. Thanks

Comment: hey u have not registered ur activity in manifest plz check it once

Comment: @user2511113 post the code also and check if you have updated adt to rev 22

Comment: The same code is working perfectly on another system.
My guess is that there could be something wrong in the android installation or the java installation.
Can someone please tell me how i could fix that?

Comment: The Android manifest page gives me an error now. It says: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'neverEncrypt' in package 'android'at                                                        <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Presbelg"

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
android:name=".your_activity_name"
</activity>
```

Comment: its not `activitynotfoundexception`. its `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @Raghunandan "Unable to instantiate activity" says that only i think.

Comment: I made the change. The app crashes even now.Same errors in the logCat

Comment: @user2511113 and post your code also. Also check if you have updated adt to rev 22

Comment: hey but  launching activity as shown above is initial, is there any other activity other than initial in ur application? did u registered all activities in ur application?

Comment: @user2511113 i would suggest you to rename your activity to something like `InitalActivity`. In the activity tag i would mention `android:name="com.belgium.initial.InitialActivity"`

Comment: But the same code is working perfectly on another system. My guess is that there could be something wrong in the android installation or the java installation. Is there anyway to figure that out?

Comment: And no. There are no other activities other than initial.

Comment: @user2511113 just for clarification is your adt rev 22?. Works on Another system? but in your case it's a classcastexception.

Comment: oops then u need to check if ur properly installing the apk on version u have built for

Comment: Yes, The project works fine on another system. This was just copied and imported into my workspace.

Comment: The Android manifest page gives me an error now. It says: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'neverEncrypt' in package 'android'at <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="Presbelg"